# Why does Ubuntu logins to an Orange Screen?

Tags: unity

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC replacing with with Windows XP.

Installation is successfully done and I can login in to system. But the desktop doesn't appear. It only shows an orange screen. I had waited too much but not success to get to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to enter low graphics mode please? When logging in click on the Ubuntu button next to your name and select "Ubuntu fallback" (or something along those lines). If that doesn't work, either your installation is defective or this is a bug.  If this is a bug, then you should report it on [Ubuntu's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu).